# Как называется паттерн, когда необходимо упростить создание объекта?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Например, я использую стороннюю Либу, и каждый раз при ее использовании я не хочу писать много кода для создания и конфигурирования самого объекта.

Я хочу часть дефолтных параметров для моего проекты завернуть в готовый метод, чтобы каждый раз, как только мне нужен объект, я получал уже сконфигурированный объект с дефолтными настойками.

Comment: Dependency Injection Container, но если даже не слышали о таком, то будет сложно. Можете попробовать начать с Service Locator. Если и это окажется сложным, то Singleton

Comment: Либо Фабрика, либо Строитель (Builder).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z8ICbPItRI&ab_channel=DmitryAfanasyev

Comment: видимо речь идет о `Factory`